# What does "ea" mean?

Tags: meaning

> -MENU-
>
> Sourdough - 4ea

I searched and found out that "ea" stands for "each". Then, regarding the example above, does it mean that this "Sourdough" menu will provide 4 sourdoughs? Or does it mean that each person will get 4 sourdoughs? I think the latter one doesn't make sense, but I want to make sure if my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that "ea" means "each" here. Most likely though this refers to a price rather than specifying a quantity of the food item.

More casual places may not explicitly use a dollar sign ($) or the word dollars with a price.